# MarionetteJS and not understanding behaviors

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, behavior

Here is my behavior:

```
define(['marionette'], function (Marionette){
    'use strict';

    var Filter = Marionette.Behavior.extend({
        events: {
            'keyup @ui.filter': 'onFilter'
        },

        defaults: {
            field: "name"
        },

        onFilter: function () {
            console.log(this.options.field);
            console.log(this.view);
        }
    });

    return Filter;
});
```

Here is how I am using it

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'marionette', 'text!components/slide-out-menu/template.html', 'eventer',
        'behaviors/behavior.filter'],
function (_, $, Marionette, templateHTML, eventer, Filter) {
    'use strict';

    var SlideOutMenuView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
        tagName: 'section',
        className: 'menu open',
        template: _.template(templateHTML),

        ui: {
            next: '.next',
            prev: '.prev',
            cancel: '.cancel',
            submit: '.submit',
            title: 'header h1',
            filter: 'header input',
            toggleGroups: '.toggle-groups',
            toggleSegments: '.toggle-segments'
        },

        events: {
            'click @ui.cancel': 'menuClose',
            'click @ui.submit': 'updateSelection',
            'click @ui.next': 'onNextClick',
            'click @ui.prev': 'onPrevClick',
            'click @ui.toggleGroups, @ui.toggleSegments': 'onToggleClick'
        },

        behaviors: {
            Filter: {
                behaviorClass: Filter
            }
        },
```

But I am needing the behavior to transcend into an `ItemView`like this:

```
var GroupItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'article',

    template: _.template(templateHTML),

    ui: {
        input: 'input'
    },

    events: {
        'click': 'onSelect'
    },

    behaviors: {
        Filter: {
            behaviorClass: Filter,
            field: "group_name"
        }
    },
```

The behavior triggers obviously from inside the `LayoutView` but I can't get it to fire inside the `ItemView`... the `@ui.filter` property is apart of the LayoutView, so maybe that's my problem, but how would that transcend down to the ItemView?

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure I'm following but can you try bubbling up an event from the ItemView and listening to it in the Layout?

So in the ItemView you can say:

```
triggers: 
  "click .elThatYouCareAbout": "el:clicked"
```

Then in your collection/composite view you can say (you could also listen to this in your controller if you initialize it there):

```
initialize: ->
      @on "childview:el:clicked", (child, args) =>
        @trigger "some:other:event", args
```

Then in your layout you can act on that event. You might not even really need the Behavior with this not that I kind of think about it - I've never actually used one with this model of pub/sub/messaging to different parts of the app.

(excuse the coffeescript) :)